# ASP.NET if condition on databind value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, data-binding

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="CustLink_File" style="text-decoration: none; color:blue;" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompName") %>' >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Hi, how can i put if condition on 
 `Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompName") %>'` . 
Lets say i have 2 condition which is custName and CompName.. Thanks

Comment: So based on condition you want to display either company name or customer name? What is the condition here to check?

Comment: You can do this from code-behind.

Comment: Text='<%#SomeFunction(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompName")) %>'